# How to display two separate lists of two different models declared in ListView in one HTML template in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have coded a ListView for search engine. I wanted to extract data from fields of two different models. First, I declared separate lists for each model. Then I combined them into one list as shown below.

```
view.py
class SearchView(ListView):
    template_name = 'articles/search_view.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        object_list = Article.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=query) | Q(description__icontains=query)|
                                             Q(body__icontains=query) |
                                             Q(stocks_etfs_or_bonds__ticker__icontains=query) |
                                             Q(stocks_etfs_or_bonds__description__icontains=query) |
                                             Q(stocks_etfs_or_bonds__name__icontains=query) |
                                             Q(tags__name__icontains=query))
        securities_list = StockETFBond.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=query))
        search_result = list(chain(object_list, securities_list))
        return search_result
```

In this case, the template will display one list of two models.

```
search_view.html template now
{% for object in object_list %}
    {{ object }}
{% endfor %}
```

But I would like to be able to display two separate lists of two different models in the template as shown below.

```
search_view.html
{% for object in object_list %}
    {{ object }}
{% endfor %}
{% for object in securities_list %}
    {{ object }}
{% endfor %}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, ListView will only send data returned by the queryset. To get two lists you will have to override the context.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    query = self.request.GET.get('q')
    # Additional context data
    context['securities_list'] = StockETFBond.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=query))
    return context
```